# Using Web View HTML in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using a web view in my app and load the url "http://google.com"
now I want to automatically search the word that I input in a TextView.

thnx for answering I just use this and it works

```
String qString ="http://www.google.com/search?q=%s";
String test="dogs";
String q = qString + test;
web.loadUrl(q);
```

a very simple way. sigh

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://www.google.com/search?q=dogs

Replace the dogs with whatever was in the text field.

Comment: I can I replace it by a variable not a specific word? for example String test = "dogs";    http://www.google.com/search?q=test

Answer (score 0):

Use String.format(..) method to place the arguments in the string.  So

```
     String qString ="http://www.google.com/search?q=%s";
```

is the query string.

```
     String test="dogs";  // or whatever.
     String.format(qString, test);
```

Comment: Well I think "http://www.google.com/search?q=%s" after you have applied the value to qString.